# No graphics after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

```
do-release-upgrade
```

No errors. On boot, I get a nice graphical 17.10 splash screens, then a few minutes later:

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager
```

but no graphics visible, `<Ctrl><Alt><F7>` does nothing.

I do have a backup of 17.04 but I'd rather get 17.10 working! Also I'm really trying to avoid a clean install, though I know this may be the "right thing to do"...

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get purge "nvidia*"
```

which I assume should now use `nouveau`. But exactly same occurs. So as per [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1705369), I added the `nomodeset` boot parameter

```
linux /boot/bmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic ... ro nomodeset quiet splash
```

But no change. There are no options to "Disable integrated graphics/GPU in your BIOS" in my BIOS. So then as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966667/69348) I did

```
lspci |grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller NVIDIA G96GL [Quadro FX 580]
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller NVIDIA G84 [GeForce 8600 GT]

ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias  : pci:v....
vendor    : NVIDIA corporation
model     : G84 [GeForce 8600 GT]
driver    : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver    : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver    : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro fere builtin

sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

this seems to install fine, but exactly same problem. So, then I uncommented this line

```
cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
...
WaylandEnable=false
```

Again no video. 
Note that I have 2 Nvidia cards, but this hasn't caused any problems in the past, and the Ubuntu splash screen appears nicely on both cards.

As per [this old thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1559576) I checked I have got

```
sudo apt list --installed |grep 'xorg-legacy'

xserver-xorg-legacy/arflu 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Anyone know how to fix this now? I am assuming this must be a graphics driver problem, but I have tried all combinations I can think of.  At this point I don't mind whether I use nouveau or nvidia, with X or wayland...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try a live USB first to see how 17.10 would run on your hardware?

Comment: Now that would have been sensible :-)  actually I couldn't get my bios to see the live USB, no idea why (it worked on another machine)...