# nVidia X Settings does not launch- Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

(specs Lenovo U-31
 Processor
Intel Core i7-5500U (Intel Core i7)
Graphics adapter
NVIDIA GeForce 920M - 2048 MB, Core: 954 MHz, Memory: 900 MHz, DDR3

also includes the typical Intel Graphics 5500)

My problem is simple. I have installed the proprietery drivers and I have installed the nVidia settings software through sudo apt install nvidia-settings.

It installed fine and it appears on my app drawer however whenever I click on it, it never launches. Basically nothing happens. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running nvidia settings ? Wayland ? As far as I know wayland is not supported, your results may be spotty. If you are using sudo, it will not work in wayland.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia driver?  Ubuntu's "Software & Updates",... Additional drivers method of driver installation also installs the Nvidia-settings, so I suspect you did something else.  Does lshw -c video show the nvidia driver in use?

Comment: You might get some helpful error information if you open a terminal window and type `sudo nvidia-settings`

Comment: @OttoV sudo will not work out of the box with wayland https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961975#961975

Comment: You can still type nvidia-settings w/o sudo, you just won't have permissions to **save** system-level files. Also, Wayland and Nvidia drivers currently are incompatible, so you could [disable wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966666/after-the-upgrade-to-17-10-i-only-get-a-black-screen-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: Thanks for your answers but the problem persists,  is there another way to easily switch between my nVidia and Intel Graphics cards ?

Comment: You can switch from wayland to Xorg as explained here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/973806/nvidia-settings-error-after-upgrade-to-17-10