# Ubuntu 17.10 black screen after login, no updates, just hibernate

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, hibernate

I started to have this issue **without** doing any updates or upgrades. My laptop suddenly became unresponsive and I had to do a hard reset. The computer boots up and the first suspicious thing is that I see the plymouth purple screen, but inside there is a big black rectangle. Afterwards I log in as usual, but only a black screen appears. I can see my mouse cursor, but I cannot interact with the system in any way. Also, a strange thing, the system fan starts going full speed a couple of seconds after I login. This would indicate that the system is doing something.

I tried to reinstall the desktop completely using [this guide](http://helewix.com/howto/ubuntu-17-10-black-screen-solution/). No effect.

I tried to uninstall Nvidia drivers following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966667). No effect.

My issue seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743094), but I am not sure, since it is not clear whether or not the problem described therein remains after reboot. Mine does.

I tried to test out all the linux kernels that I have available in my GRUB's advanced boot settings for Ubuntu, again to no avail.

I am truly perplexed, since I am innocent of any tinkering with drivers or updates. Any guide whatsoever is most welcome.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you boot from live media?

Comment: @ELderGeek no, from live media it was ok. I have no idea what happened. This was the first time in 10 years of Ubuntuing that I got hit by such a thing. I eventually gave up and reinstalled the system, which helped :)

Comment: I highly recommend keeping an eye on your syslog. From what you are saying here it seems likely that you may have a storage device with weak or failing sectors. You might get some advance warning from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)