# What could cause this glitch in gedit?

Tags: graphics, 18.04, gedit

I was casually working with my Ubuntu 18.04, when all of a sudden the desktop ceased to be responsive. I restarted the system and booted to a black screen with mouse pointer and the CPU fan going all guns blazing.

This thing happened to me before with 17.10 and as I described in my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1013901/64420), this was completely unprovoked on my side. I did not do any installs or upgrades, so **none** of the answers to the questions linked as duplicates apply.

Elder Geek suggested that I check my harddrive for failures. I ran the SMART diagnosis and everything was OK.

Knowing that the only way out was to re-install the system, I did exactly that, only to find that the **gedit** text editor is behaving glitchy on resize and text editing. Kate, the other text editor, does not have this problem.

[image: gedit Ubuntu 18.04 glitch]

I checked my system logs, but I have no idea what any of that information means and if it could be the cause of this glitch.

```
14:34:48 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
14:34:47 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
14:34:37 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
14:34:36 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
14:34:34 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
14:34:34 kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
14:34:34 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
14:34:34 kernel: [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
```

Has anybody had a similar problem? Are these log messages benign, or could some of them have caused this glitch?

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/838259/gedit-has-a-transparent-background-since-upgrade-to-16-10/840073#840073

Comment: @heynnema Thank you! I deleted the file, rebooted, and the problem is gone!

Comment: @heynnema, I also have this spice error in my 18.04, but there are no .xinputrc in my machine. :(